# Large Gif animation

Tags: php, animation, load, gif

For a browsergame I would like to make around ten different gif layers with animating things on it. Which of the ten layers I display depends on the city points. In Flash games like Die Siedler Online I see many animated things but I dont see that in PHP text based browsergames like TribalWars. Why not? Does that require much bandwith or does it load very slow...?

I have another question about the gif animations. Should I make a large layer with transparent backgrond and with 20 animated things on it or should I make 20 different gif animations like TribalWars?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Gif is small but big when animated, and it takes a lot of bandwidth
- Why would you want to use animated gifs when you can use javascript? (jQuery)
- About your last question, go for first one. It takes less resources from your server and it's smaller than 20 files of same type.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use GIFs, they're basically deprecated. You can create several different images and just animate one layer of it using various javascript libraries.

Take a look at this - http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/10-impressive-javascript-animation-frameworks/ It should help with exactly what you need. You can also use librarys such as MooTools and jQuery for the animation.

Another one I'd recommend you look at is [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/). It may be a bit too extensive for what you need but allows for advanced animations which are vector based, using the HTML canvas.

Furthermore, you could also look into such libraries as [ThreeJS](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/), which allows you to use WebGL to make 3D games, however this is probably too much for what you need.

Good luck with your project

Comment: Thank you very much. But is the bandwith for such frameworks high? I mean, it is very strange that other browsergames doesn't have many animated things while you can make cool things with it.

Comment: Compared to a gif it's not slower.. because javascript loads after DOM and the images / graphics will load on the fly, it wont have too much effect on loading times. Most browsergames are text based as thats how theyre designed to work. Take a look at www.chromeexperiments.com for some good examples of javascript games. Most people have only just started to adopt games in javascript as well.

Comment: Thanks for your examples. Now I know how I can 'walk' a character, but in a Gif animation you have many different frames (for example 20). But in the examples you gave me don't see it. How can I make an animated character with different frames? I don't understand:-)

Comment: As jQuery animations are performed in a linear transition as opposed to frames, this would be more difficult. However you can use jQuery, for example, to hide/show divs in a time. $fx also allows chaining, why do you specifically need frames? what is the animation effect you are looking for?

Comment: I would like to make a 'city-life' animation. When a city is very small, you can see two people walking on the streets. But if the city is very large you can see smoke from houses, ten people walking on the streets, animals and more. The total city map is around 700x500px. When possible I like it that people can walk to the right, and after a point, they walk to the left (so the animation should be changed in a left-walking man). Hope you understand me, with my bad English:D

Comment: No problem. For that I should advise using the canvas. Maybe something like this? http://processingjs.org/

Comment: Thanks. I'm very very bad in these things. But I don't see images with different frames. An example of what I mean is this one: http://static.grepolis.com/images/game/visual/worker2_sprite.png. They animate the frame with JQuery I think (I'm not sure), but it isn't a gif animation.

Comment: Moving to chat to prevent extended discussion

Comment: @Jordy let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2528/discussion-between-rickyduck-and-jordy)

Comment: Ok, the chat doesn't work I think? Can you see my last question in the chat?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side scripting language. It has **nothing** todo with the layout. With jQuery (sort of advanced JavaScript) you could create dynamic layouts (like used in games).